# Using \Letter symbol in ifsym package

Tags: symbols, packages

Here is what I did:

1. I downloaded `ifsym` package from MiKTeX Package Manager. (MPM)
2. I added the line to my .tex file:

   ```
   \usepackage{ifsym}
   ```
3. I tried typing `\Letter` in the document.

but it doesn't work.

The `\Letter` is a symbol in `ifsym` package if I know correctly, which looks like an envelope.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use

```
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
```

since this symbol is only defined when using the `misc` package option.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the source `\Letter` is only defined if you use

```
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the package `bbding`:

```
\usepackage{bbding}
```

and after author name type `\Envelope`

Example: `Alex Anderson \Envelope` or if you want the envelope sign within bracket type: `Alex Anderson ( \Envelope )`

Be successful.